# Bluetooth LE Error GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

What does error **GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION** mean?
I sent 240044 bytes from TI CC2564, but when android received about 70000 bytes, Android show error **GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION**. I saw the problem is only on Nexus 7 with **CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH**.

Thanks all.

Comment: Hi, tôi cũng đang gặp vấn đề này. Từ đó đến này đã 3 năm, cuối cùng bạn đã tìm được câu trả lời chưa?